# Is it possible to "unload"/discard properties read from a file when accessing a new target?

Tags: ant, properties

ajust by curiosity... and because I - of course - would like to implement it that way ;)

I have several main targets in a script. Each of them builds software bundles for different regions and/or brands.

Some of my predecessors have addressed a problem to provide the targets with information which parameters/properties to use.

These entries did occur several times in each target and some values where added/hard coded even if a property already was loaded and available. This approach is very prone to errors.

This resulted in much hassle as there where typos in the names which caused a target to use a mix of variant properites instead of the one specified for each target.
In some cases did obviously lazyness succeed so instead of searching, opening and amending the appropriate variant property file was just a different one used for a single task.

I have now adapted the script that each target only requires one property file name at the beginning and the rest is then - if necessary - composed at runtime.

So far so good BUT earlier was it possible to build several targets in a row because the property file hasn't been read in the main target.

Now each target has to be built step by step as the follow up target else would use the initial properties loaded from the first target.

I have tried it with different ways of loading the property file, overwriting it with an variable but no joy so far.
I tried <**loadproperties**>, <**property file=...**>, <**propertyfile...**> all not really of help as properties can't be overwritten except you do the trick with using a variable of the same name and unset it, which won't work at this specific point.
Properties send from out side would be disregarded as I would have to initialize the value at start and I don't know which value will be used before I build.

*I thought that reading the property file line by line as a normal text file, searching for the relevant entries and assigning them to individual variables would do the trick, but I can't figure out how to achieve this :/*

I hope someone can help me with this.
An example of how a main target looks like, is attached to the end of the post.
The place I want to read values from a text (key=value) and assign them to variables is directly after the condition.

Cheers
Jan

```
<target name="Int_XX_XX_XX" description="Create XX XX release (PCSim, Front, XX)">
    <condition property="skip.target">
        <istrue value="${skip_target}" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties>
        <file file="variants/XX_XXXXXX_XX.properties"/>
    </loadproperties>
    <propertyregex property="sop.number" select="\2" input="${variant.release.label}" regexp="(\.*)_(SOP[0-9]*)" />
    <if>
        <or>
            <and>
                <available file="${variant.release.label}${variant.sub.region}.zip" />
                <istrue value="${variant.split.to.region}" />
            </and>
            <and>
                <available file="${variant.release.label}.zip" />
                <isfalse value="${variant.split.to.region}" />
            </and>
        </or>
        <then>
            <var name="bundle.exists" value="true" />
            <echo>${variant.release.label}.zip found. Skipping build target</echo>
        </then>
    </if>
    <if>
        <not>
            <istrue value="${bundle.exists}" />
        </not>
        <then>
            <echo>${variant.release.label}.zip not found. Accessing build target</echo>
            <antcall target="private.create.zip.and.pcsim">
                <param name="zip.dsitracer.client.asia" value="true" />
                <param name="variant.properties" value="variants/${variant.label}.properties" />
                <param name="echo.release.labels" value="false" />
            </antcall>
            <antcall target="private.echo.release.labels">
                <param file="variants/${variant.label}.properties" />
            </antcall>
            <antcall target="private.send.email.to.testers">
                <param name="variant.release.label" value="${variant.release.label}" />
                <param file="variants/${variant.label}.properties" />
            </antcall>
        </then>
    </if>
    <var name="bundle.exists" unset="true" />
</target>
```

Comment: try... http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html

Comment: Does it help? I haven't used it... just known when reading through the document.

Comment: It should work but it doesn't at all for some reason...

I have kept strict to the example of apache org and amended it for my purpose without any luck.

"create-release.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type local
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place."

I did then simply copy&paste the example unchanged into the script and the result was the same.

It fails at <local name="foo"/>. also assigning it a value did not give any joy.

Comment: ant-contrib is not used in this example but it is part of the system. So this can't be the reason.
It will only work with Ant 1.8 or higher, we use Ant 1.8.2

Comment: I went to another department to run a cross-check on a different buildsystem with more or less same setup.
It worked there... so what is the difference?
I run it in eclipse like they do but maybe there can be some changes causing this behaviour?
They run Ant 1.8.1, I 1.8.2.
Ant-contrib: they 0.3, I 0.3 (even if not used in this case)

Comment: Oh... me dumb, me gone go in cave, whack some meat, me feed...
Our Jenkins picks the task, eclipse not because the ant 1.8.2 is installed but Eclipse was working with 1.7..

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm :)

I had to remove the initial assignment of the property value

```
<property name="foo" value="foo"/>
```

directly after taskdef as there are are some target in the same script called by the main target. That resulted in a reread of the property value which reverted the value to foo.
Discarding the initialization does not seem to make any harm.

So my build script now has the following as addition:

```
<target name="Int_XX_XX_XX" description="Create XX XX release (PCSim, Front, XX)">
    <condition property="skip.target">
        <istrue value="${skip_target}" />
    </condition>
    <local name="variant.property.file.name" />
    <local name="variant.release.label" />
    <local name="variant.sub.region" />
    <local name="variant.split.to.region" />
    <local name="variant.label" />
    <local name="variant.label.extended" />
    <property name="variant.property.file.name" value="XX_XXXXXX_XX" />
    <loadproperties>
        <file file="variants/${variant.property.file.name}.properties" />
    </loadproperties>
```

instead of

```
    <target name="Int_XX_XX_XX" description="Create XX XX release (PCSim, Front/Rear, XX)">
    <condition property="skip.target">
        <istrue value="${skip_target}" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties>
        <file file="variants/XX_XXXXXX_XX.properties" />
    </loadproperties>
```

by the way

```
        <local name="variant.release.label" />
    <local name="variant.sub.region" />
    <local name="variant.split.to.region" />
    <local name="variant.label" />
    <local name="variant.label.extended" />
```

are properties also used in the main target, the targets on sub-levels do use the properties read from the recent property file and discard them later on as expected.

Thanks for helping :)